# Keycloak OpenID Client without browser

Tags: keycloak, openid

#### Problematic

I have a working Keycloak in production and I need my users to log into a mobile app, developed using react native using that Keycloak. Till now I was using the normal login flow through the in-app browser as AppAtuh, but now I received a request from users, to say in the app while logging in.

#### What I've tried

- I made the Keycloak theme for the mobile login ressemble the Mobile App UI so much, that it could be just opened using react WebView as a normal screen.

  On the paper, this idea works, but in real life, I cannot take advantage of the Keycloak ID cookie placed. So whenever the WebView open, a new session with cookies are generated. It's not useful.
- I started calling keycloak endpoints myself from inside the mobile app. It's not an easy job, because some endpoints doesn't works because of OTP configurations that I've done.

  Secondly, this Idea works for simple process like `login`, but does not work very well for `registration` or `reset-password`. And it's just an example. My Kecloak does have a list of `Authenticator`s which uses `phoneNumber` and some cookies to login.

#### Specifications

- I'm using Keycloak 10 (started with keycloak 6 a year ago)
- The mobile app is developed using React Native and Expo. Tthe first login flow was using the library [Expo AppAuth](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/app-auth/) and the second, [React native WebView](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v38.0.0/sdk/webview/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [that](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app)? I think you should consider using [Custom URI scheme](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#redirect-uri_custom-scheme) for your Keycloak OpenID Connect client and use default phone browser. [This](https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Hi. I went through all these links and it's stated what is actually already implemented. Now, I want users not to notify that we're using a browser

Comment: I checked Audible's android login page and it's the same idea I wanna implement. Please check it as example

Comment: As you mentioned there are some problems because of OTP, new session with cookies and other things so if you want your Keycloak to work you need to use browser or something like [Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs). I checked Audible and maybe it is something like [Trusted Web Activity](https://developers.google.com/web/android/trusted-web-activity)?